# Creating a scrolling grid of images using WPF and XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I currently have the following XAML code but when I run my app, the ScrollBars appear but I am unable to scroll through the list of images (scrollbar doesn't work).

```
<Window x:Class="WPFMediaManager.MoviePanel"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MoviePanel" Height="1024" Width="1473.254" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">

    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplate">
            <WrapPanel>
                <Image Width="200" Height="300" Stretch="Fill" Source="{Binding}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
            </WrapPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid x:Name="movie_grid">
        <ListView Grid.Row="4" Name ="MovieListView" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path = movie_posters_list}">
            <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <UniformGrid Columns="5" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemsPanel>
        </ListView>
        <TextBlock Name="SampleTextBlock" Text="{Binding Path=movie_names}" DataContext="{StaticResource ItemTemplate}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I'm not sure what is causing this issue and whether I'm using the appropriate containers to house the images.

My goal is something like the following layout:

[image]

C# Code behind:

```
namespace WPFMediaManager {
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MoviePanel.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MoviePanel : Window {
        public MoviePanel() {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

    List<ImageSource> movie_posters_list = new List<ImageSource>();
        List<String> movie_names = new List<String>();
        String regex_pattern = @"\\([\w ]+).(?:jpg|png)$";


        public void LoadImages() {
            //Image current_image;
            String movie_poster_path = @"C:\Users\Vax\Desktop\movie_posters";
            List<String> filenames = new List<String>(System.IO.Directory.EnumerateFiles(movie_poster_path, "*.jpg"));

            foreach (String filename in filenames) {
                this.movie_posters_list.Add(new BitmapImage(new Uri(filename)));
                Console.WriteLine("filename " + filename);
                Match regex_match = Regex.Match(filename.Trim(), regex_pattern);
                String matched_movie_name = regex_match.Groups[1].Value;
                this.movie_names.Add(matched_movie_name);
                Console.WriteLine("Movie Name: " + matched_movie_name);

            }

            MovieListView.ItemsSource = movie_posters_list;
        }

}

}
```

Edit: I tried the method outlined by @XAML Lover but I don't get the images appearing at all anymore. I'm not sure whether this is a data binding issue.

Comment: please post the code of **movie_posters_list**; do you mean after adopting the code by @XAML lover the images disappear, and with your original code the images were displayed well?

Comment: Yes, I was getting images with my previous code but it wasn't scrollable.

Comment: but his code and yours are almost identical, except for the layout changes; and from your code behind, `LoadImages` is not called, maybe that is why.

Comment: `LoadImages` gets called by a Button Listener in another class. It is as follows: MoviePanel moviePanel = new MoviePanel();  moviePanel.LoadImages(); moviePanel.Show();

Comment: you need to debug yourself... the images are showing on my side.

Comment: I'm not sure what happened but after closing and restarting Visual Studio it seemed to work. Thanks everyone for the help.

Comment: @OsborneCox can you post your full source code for this? I am wanting to do something similar and this would be a great building block for me!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The TextBlock is hiding the whole ListView, which is blocking the user input. Look at the modified XAML,

```
<Grid x:Name="movie_grid">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ListView Grid.Row="1"
              Name="MovieListView"
              ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemTemplate}"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Path = movie_posters_list}">
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <UniformGrid Columns="5" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
    </ListView>
    <TextBlock Name="SampleTextBlock"
               Text="{Binding Path=movie_names}"
               DataContext="{StaticResource ItemTemplate}" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: I tried this way and none of the images appear. I just get a blank grid unfortunately.

Comment: @OsborneCox if your original issue (_scrollbar doesn't work_) had been solved, but unfortunately you found other issue, you should edit your original question, appending the new issue to the end; or, if the new issue is not relevant to the original one, you should accept the answer and ask a new question.

Comment: @kennyzx I've amended the question.

Comment: I've marked the answer as correct as the issue wasn't with the code itself. Closing and restarting Visual Studio made it work.

Answer (score 2):

Put your xaml of displaying the pictures in a grid then put that grid inside scrollviewer control and set the desired orientation and alignments and you will get the solution.

```
<ScrollViewer orientation="" VerticleAllignment="" HorizontalAllignment="">
<Grid>
Place your xaml here...
</Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```